How to show the given function is differentiable...?
Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\begin{equation}f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(x-y)^2\sin \frac{1}{x-y},&\text{ if } x\ne y\\0 ,&\text{ if } x=y\end{cases}\end{equation}$$
Then which of the following is true
(1) f is continuous at $(0,0)$
(2)The partial derivative $f_x$ does not exists at $(0,0)$
(3)$f_x$ continuous at $(0,0)$
(4)$f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$
For option 2,
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}f_x &=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\sin 1/h-0}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}h\sin 1/h\\&=0\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
So similarly $f_y$
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}f_y &=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0,0+h)-f(0,0)}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\sin 1/(0-h)-0}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}-h\sin 1/h\\&=0\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
So both partial derivatives exists. so option 2 is incorrect.
Since $f_x=0$, can I say it is continuous at $(0,0)$....?
For Option 1, to check continuity at $(0,0)$ I used the continuity definition and it is getting continuous at $(0,0)$
It is given correct options are 1 and 4.
And I am not getting how to show it is differentiable. and also why option 3 is incorrect.
Please let me know
Thanks in advance!!

actually this is multiple choice question, you need to choose the correct options... so here 1 and 4 are correct, but I am doubtful about how to show 4 is correct and why 3 is incorrect

For (3) - consider $f_x$ as multivariable function and show that it is not continuous by considering what happens for points on the line $y = x$ and what for the other

I computed $f_x$ by differentiating with respect to $x$, and got $f_x=2(x-y)\sin \frac{1}{x-y}-\cos\frac{1}{x-y}$ Now I am checking limit across $y=x$, sine term is getting vanish but 2nd term is becomes $\cos \infty$ which is not defined...similarly if I check across $x=0$ still get infinity...Am I doing correct..

A function $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be differentiable at point $x_0$ if
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\|f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-Jh\|}{\|h\|}=0$$
where $J$ is the Jacobian matrix. For your function at $x_0 = [\begin{matrix}0 & 0\end{matrix}]^T$ obviously $J = [\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \end{matrix}]$. Thus the equation is simplified to
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\|f(h)\|}{\|h\|}=0$$
The LHS is the same expression as the partial derivatives at $x_0$, which are $0$, hence this equation is true, therefore the function is differentiable at $x_0$.
To prove that $(3)$ is false let's consider $f_x$ on the line $D: y = 0$. If it's continuous at $(0,0)$ then it must also be continuous on this line. We have
$$f_{x\mid (x,y)\in D\setminus\{(0,0)\}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}$$
$2x\sin\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow 0$ when $x \rightarrow 0$. However $\cos \frac{1}{x}$ does not approach anything when $x \rightarrow 0$. Thus $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f_x$ does not exist for $y = 0$. Therefore $f_x$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$
